# Can you distinguish the use of useRef, useCallback and useMemo in React-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**explain with example if possible.**

Comment: did you check the react doc?

Comment: Yes Sword, I've checked it but I'm not able to understand properly.

Answer (score 0):

**With useCallback you can define a function that has referential equality between renders.**

**You can use useMemo to calculate a value that has referential equality between renders.strong text**

```
useCallback(fn, deps);
useMemo(fn, deps);
```

**The useRef Hook is a function that returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized with the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.**

```
const refContainer = useRef(initialValue);
```

For More Information Visit Following Link:
[UseRef](https://medium.com/trabe/react-useref-hook-b6c9d39e2022)
[UseCallback vs UseMemo](https://medium.com/@jan.hesters/usecallback-vs-usememo-c23ad1dc60#:%7E:text=In%20other%20words%2C%20useCallback%20gives,equality%20between%20renders%20for%20values.&text=The%20difference%20is%20that%20useCallback,function%20and%20returns%20the%20result.)